# How to specify pre-emptible SPOT VMs in Airflow cluster creation operator

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

Cluster creation through GCP console or GCP API provides an option to specify secondary workers`[SPOT, pre-emptible or non-preemptible]`. However, not able to find the corresponding CLUSTER_CONFIG to use while cluster creation through AirFlow operator. By default, the secondary workers are pre-emptible and not SPOT VMs.
Attaching UI screenshot
[image: GCP console options]
Airflow secondary worker node configs.

```json
"secondary_worker_config": {
        "num_instances": 5,
        "machine_type_uri": SOME_MACHINE_TYPE,
        "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},
        "image_uri" : SOME_IMAGE_URI
    }
```

Need suggestion on Airflow secondary worker payload change to create SPOT workers.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preemptibility`](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/ClusterConfig#Preemptibility) parameter:

```json
"secondaryWorkerConfig": {
    "numInstances": "2",
    "machineTypeUri": "n1-standard-4",
    "diskConfig": {
      "bootDiskType": "pd-standard",
      "bootDiskSizeGb": 500
    },
    "preemptibility": "SPOT"
}
```

Comment: @NehaRanjan But Airflow `DataprocCreateClusterOperator` operator uses the same API, so you can pass this config in your `cluster_config` argument. See [create-a-cluster](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html#create-a-cluster)

Comment: Looking for airflow payload, dataproc api is already working for me. Below is the airflow config "secondary_worker_config": {
        "num_instances": 5,
        "machine_type_uri": SOME_MACHINE_TYPE,
        "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", 
            "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},
        "image_uri" : SOME_IMAGE_URI,
        "preemptibility": "SPOT"
    }
ValueError: unknown enum label "Spot"

Comment: getting error : ValueError: unknown enum label "Spot" .. Can it be related to version?

Comment: This is my config.. CLUSTER_CONFIG = {"master_config": {"num_instances": 1,"machine_type_uri": MACHINE_TYPE,"disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},"image_uri" : IMAGE_URI},"worker_config": {"num_instances": 10,"machine_type_uri": MACHINE_TYPE,"disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},"image_uri" : IMAGE_URI},"secondary_worker_config": {"num_instances": 5,"machine_type_uri": MACHINE_TYPE,"disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},"image_uri" : IMAGE_URI,"preemptibility": "SPOT"}}

Comment: hey @NehaRanjan were you able to solve this? I encountered similar problem with this